# SQL_NO_CACHE picks row with same value as previous selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL statement that is meant to pick a random row from a database that has about 5,000 rows.

I've noticed some odd behavior for a query that is supposed to randomly select one row. Here is my query:

`SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM tickets AS r1 JOIN (SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tickets)) AS id) AS r2 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id ORDER BY r1.id ASC LIMIT 1`

My table structure is:

`id int(11) primary auto_increment
name int(11)`

After the query picks a row, the row is deleted. When the page is refreshed, a row with the same name value is picked almost 9/10 times. I've put the SQL_NO_CACHE statement to try and avoid that, but it hasn't worked. Even if a certain name value is only 100/5,000, it still gets picked 9 times in a row, which is not what I expect the query to be doing.

Does anyone have any input as to why this is happening, or any possible fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it is your browser, or some (transparent) HTTP proxy, that is cacheing the *page* rather than anything on the server that is cacheing the MySQL *result*?  Have you set appropriate no-cache HTTP headers?

Comment: Can you show the delete statement?

Comment: The probability of any given record being selected will be distributed with the values of the `id` column.  Are the `id` values uniformly distributed between `1` and `MAX(id)`?

Comment: I have no set no-cache HTTP headers, or atleast I do not think I have. The delete statement is `mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM `tickets` WHERE `id`='".$row['id']."'");` where $row is a ticket that has the a matching `name` value from the query above, but DOES NOT have to be the exact row selected from the query.

Comment: @eggyal: No, there are breaks between the first and last row. The query located above was from a previous StackOverflow question to account for breaks.

Comment: It "accounts for breaks" insofar as it will always return a result, but the probabilities of any record being selected will be weighted according to the size of the gap that precedes it.

Comment: @eggyal - Do you know of any way to adjust the query to avoid that, so that each row is weighted how they should be?

Comment: Would it be wiser to, instead of creating and destroying rows in the `tickets` table, then to just UPDATE them to reflect the new values, so there will not be any breaks?

Comment: No, it is better to filter on a criterion that is proportionate to number of remaining records: `SELECT tickets.* FROM tickets, (SELECT @c:=COUNT(*)+1 FROM tickets) t WHERE RAND() < 1/@c:=@c-1 LIMIT 1`.  If there is any risk of concurrent sessions accessing the table, you will either need to `LOCK tickets` prior to performing the `SELECT` (if using MyISAM) or else use a locking read by appending `FOR UPDATE` to the above query (if using InnoDB within a transaction).

Comment: However, none of that answers why the row is not appearing to be deleted.  Have you directly inspected the database (e.g. using the mysql command line client, or a web-based tool like phpMyAdmin) to see whether the `DELETE` operation was successful?